# GM_registerMenuCommand is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, cross-browser, greasemonkey

everybody. I'm puzzled as to why I keep getting the error "GM_registerMenuCommand is not defined" when I try to run a userscript that I created. I have tried this in Firefox using Scriptish 1.0b9 and the latest version of Greasemonkey. I even disabled all addons except Scriptish to see if it was a conflict, but with no joy.

I'm including jQuery in my userscript using [this template by Erik Vold](http://erikvold.com/blog/index.cfm/2010/6/14/using-jquery-with-a-user-script). Before trying this template, I put the exact same code block in the template proposed by Joan Piedra and everything worked fine. Unfortunately, Piedra's template did not work in Chrome, which is something that I think is necessary, considering Chrome's growing userbase. The snippet that's throwing the error is below:

```
    // a function that loads jQuery and calls a callback function when jQuery has finished loading
function addJQuery(callback) {
  var script = document.createElement("script");
  script.setAttribute("src", "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js");
  script.addEventListener('load', function() {
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.textContent = "(" + callback.toString() + ")();";
    document.body.appendChild(script);
  }, false);
  document.body.appendChild(script);
}

// the guts of this userscript
function main() {


var isLevelupMove = false;
var isTutorMove = false;
var isTM = false;
var TMhead = $('#moves\\:machine');
var hasSecondEvo = false;
var hasFinalEvo1 = false;
var hasFinalEvo2 = false;
var header = $('.header-row').eq(1);
var TMmoves = new Array();

//This section deals with the user-defined colors 

GM_registerMenuCommand("Color for pre-evolutionary-only moves", prevoColorPrompt);
GM_registerMenuCommand("Color for first evolution-only moves", evoColorPrompt);

if(localStorage.getItem('prevoColor') == null || localStorage.getItem('evoColor') == null)
{
    localStorage.setItem('prevoColor', 'red');
    localStorage.setItem('evoColor', 'orange');
}
var prevoColor = localStorage.getItem('prevoColor');
var evoColor = localStorage.getItem('evoColor');

function prevoColorPrompt()
{
    var input = prompt("Please enter a desired 6-digit hex color-code for pre-evolutionary pokemon:") 
    localStorage.setItem('prevoColor', '#'+input);
}

function evoColorPrompt()
{
    var input = prompt("Please enter the desired 6-digit hex color-code for first-evolution pokemon:") 
    localStorage.setItem('evoColor', '#'+input);
}

//This loop tests each 'th' element in a sample header row, determining how many Evos are currently present in the chart.

$('.header-row').eq(1).find('th').each(function(index) 
{
    if($(this).find('a').length != 0)
    {
        switch(index)
        {
            case 2:
            hasSecondEvo = true;
            break;

            case 3:
            hasFinalEvo1 = true;
            break;

            case 4:
            hasFinalEvo2 = true;
            break;
        }
    }
});

//All 'tr' siblings are TM moves, since it's the last section on the page
//This array puts only the names of the available TMs into the TMmoves array
TMhead.nextAll().each(function(index)
{
    TMmoves.push($(this).children(":first").find('a').eq(0).html());
});

$('tr').each(function(index) 
{
    var moveName = $(this).children(":first").find('a').eq(0).html();   
    moveName = $.trim(moveName);

    switch($(this).attr('id'))
    {
        case 'moves:level-up':
            isLevelupMove = true;   
            break;

        case 'moves:egg':
            isLevelupMove = false;
            break;  

        case 'moves:tutor':
            isTutorMove = true;

        case 'moves:machine':
            isTM = true;    
    }

    if(isLevelupMove || isTutorMove)
    {
        var babyMoveCell = $(this).find('td').eq(0);
        babyMoveText = $.trim(babyMoveCell.html());

        secondEvoCell = babyMoveCell.next();
        secondEvoText = $.trim(secondEvoCell.html());

        finalEvo1Cell = secondEvoCell.next();
        finalEvo1Text = $.trim(finalEvo1Cell.html());

        finalEvo2Cell = finalEvo1Cell.next();
        finalEvo2Text = $.trim(finalEvo2Cell.html());

        //This checks if evolutions have checkmarks

        if(babyMoveText.length > 0)
        {
            if(hasSecondEvo && secondEvoText.length == 0 || hasFinalEvo1 && finalEvo1Text.length == 0 || 
                hasFinalEvo2 && finalEvo2Text.length == 0)
            {
                //See if the move is a TM before proceeding 
                var tm = tmCheck(moveName);

                if(!tm)
                {

                    if(secondEvoText.length > 0)
                    {       
                        babyMoveCell.css("color", evoColor);
                        secondEvoCell.css("color", evoColor);
                        babyMoveCell.prev().find('a').eq(0).css("color", evoColor); //highlights move name
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        babyMoveCell.css("color", prevoColor);
                        babyMoveCell.prev().find('a').eq(0).css("color", prevoColor);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else if(secondEvoText.length > 0)
        {
            if(hasFinalEvo1 && finalEvo1Text.length == 0 || hasFinalEvo2 && finalEvo2Text.length == 0)
            {
                var tm = tmCheck(moveName); 

                if(!tm)
                {
                    secondEvoCell.css("color", evoColor);
                    babyMoveCell.prev().find('a').eq(0).css("color", evoColor);
                }
            }
        }
    }

});

function tmCheck(input)
{
    var isTM = false;

    //Iterate through TMmoves array to see if the input matches any entries
    for(var i = 0; i < TMmoves.length; i++)
    {   
        if(input == TMmoves[i])
        {
            isTM = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(isTM == true)
        return true;
    else
        return false;       
}

//alert("evoColor: " + localStorage.getItem('evoColor') + ". prevoColor: " + localStorage.getItem('prevoColor'))

}//end main()

// load jQuery and execute the main function
addJQuery(main);
```

[This is the userscript I'm trying to implement this for](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/98824). If anyone has any suggestions or ideas about why I'm getting the error, I'd love to hear them!

Comment: Are you getting this error on Chrome or Firefox?

Comment: Both. I would use Tampermonkey with Chrome, though, if I got it to work on Firefox.

Comment: Well, that script seem to work for me on FF 3.6. Are you using FF 4?   Suggest uninstall GM and Scriptish, restart FF, install GM only and see if that clears it.    What is the exact error message in FF's or Firebug's console?

Comment: The script as linked is the one that's working. I posted the one that's throwing the error in my original post. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: Here is my fully working workaround for this:
http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/26902/working-gm-setvalue-and-gm-getvalue-inside-jquery-greasemonkey-access-violatio

Enjoy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach will not work because `addJQuery()` is not *transferring* workspace objects to the page's scope, it's essentially recreating your code from the source.

That means that the `GM_` functions are not usable because there is no link between the sandbox and the copy of the code that `addJQuery()` made.

If your script needs `GM_` functions, then just use straight GM code with the `// @require` directive for things like jQuery.   Your only option for Chrome is Tampermonkey.

In both cases, `addJQuery()`-like tricks are not needed.

Comment: Thanks for the help, Brock! The script now works in Chrome, but it breaks if one tries to change the color (via Tampermonkey). I don't see anything in Chrome's javascript console, and the menu commands disappeared from the Tampermonkey menu after entering in a hex color code. The version I'm working on that partially works in Chrome is the latest version on the script page (linked in the OP), if you want to try it yourself.

Comment: You're using [this script](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/98824), the 3rd version now?  (It seems to have just changed.)  One thing: It's using jQuery 1.5.1.  GM used to only work reliably with jQuery 1.3.2, but I haven't (yet) tested it for GM 9, or later.  I've got to go now, I'll look further in several hours.

Comment: Alright, I've been debugging and here are some things I've tried (with no success). Any console errors are listed: 
1) Changing jQuery version to 1.3.2
2) Calling localStorage.getItem('prevoColor') from console after page load (both values null)
3) Changing from localStorage to get/setValue entirely 
4) Calling GM_getValue from the console = ReferenceError: GM_getValue is not defined 
5) Deleting localStorage entries for veekun.com in Chrome options. Sorry that it's disorganized - I don't see unordered list support for miniMarkdown.

Comment: @KongMD, Yes, the comments weren't really meant for posting questions.   ;)     I think we've answered the original issue.  Please open a new question for the continuing problem(s).   This reduces confusion, helps others when searching for similar symptoms, etc.

Comment: Yes, you're right. [The new thread is here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5286597/disappearing-menu-commands-after-user-input-in-tampermonkey)

Answer (score 2):

This does not work because, if you look carefully at what `addJQuery` does, you'll realize that it injects the code of the function you pass it into a `script` element that gets appended to the end of the `body` element.

This means that you're now working in the same space as the scripts the website has, so all `GM_*` are not going to be available. What you can do is to move some of the code which require those functions to outside the `main` function, but remember that the Greasemonkey sandbox means that code running inside the `main` function cannot communicate with code outside it directly. You can have indirect communication, through for example watching DOM manipulation, or even [`unsafeWindow`](http://wiki.greasespot.net/UnsafeWindow), but looking at your code it does not appear to be easily separateable.

Comment: `unsafeWindow` will not work for Chrome, and the `GM_` functions will not be defined at all.

Comment: @BrockAdams Of course, but my philosophy has always being that if you need cross-browser GM scripts you shouldn't be using any of those anyway - even `@require` is not supported in some browsers

Comment: True, but the OP's main concern seemed to be FF and Chrome.  Chrome's Tampermonkey extension provides support for `@require` and even limited support for `unsafeWindow`, but native, pure Chrome does not.